# edit-in-place, how to make more db fields editable

Tags: ajax, field

Good evening guys!

I just managed to implant a really sweet working edit-in-place function with jQuery and AJAX. I'm able to edit 1 db field. I would like to be able to edit multiple db fields.
These are all the scripts:

Update query (handler.php)

```
  <?php
 include('../../core/additional/connect-db.php');

if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    $query = "UPDATE players SET firstname ='$firstname' WHERE id='$id'";   
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Query couldn\'t be executed');
    if ($result) {echo 1;}
} 

?>
```

And the ajax in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".editable").hover(
            function()
            {
                $(this).addClass("editHover");
            }, 
            function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass("editHover");
            }
        );

        $(".editable").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
        $(".btnSave, .btnDiscard").live("click", handler);

        UI("Ready");

        function UI(state)
        {
            var status = {};
            status.Ready = "Ready";
            status.Post = "Saving your data. Please wait...";
            status.Success = "Success! Your edits have been saved.";
            status.Failure = "Attempts to save data failed. Please retry.";

            var background = {};
            background.Ready = "#E8F3FF";
            background.Post = "#FAD054";
            background.Success = "#B6FF6C";
            background.Failure = "#FF5353";

            $("#status").animate({opacity: 0}, 200, function (){$("#status").html(status[state]).css({background: background[state]}).animate({opacity: 1}, 200)});
        }

        function handler()
            {
                var selector="";
                var code="21";
                if ($(this).hasClass("btnSave"))
                    {
                        UI("Post");
                        var str = $(this).siblings("form").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                async: false,
                                timeout: 100,
                                url: "core/actions/handler.php",
                                data: str,
                                success: function(msg){code = msg; $(".message_edit").show(); $(".message_edit").fadeOut(2500);},                   
                        }); 
                        if(code == 1)
                        {
                            UI("Success");
                            selector = "editBox";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UI("Failure");
                            selector = "buffer";
                        }
                    }
                else {selector = "buffer"}

                $(this).parent()
                       .html($(this).siblings("form")
                                    .children("."+selector)
                                    .val())
                       .removeClass("noPad editHover")                     
                       .bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);

                return false;
            } 

        function replaceHTML()
            {
                var buffer = $(this).html()
                                    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                $(this).addClass("noPad")
                        .html("")
                        .html("<form class=\"editor\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" class=\"editBox\" value=\"" + buffer + "\" /> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"buffer\" class=\"buffer\" value=\"" + buffer + "\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" class=\"record\" value=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\" /></form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Cancel</a>")
                        .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);       
            }

    }
    ); 

    </script>
```

Then the field is displayed and editable by using this:

```
<td class="editable" id="' .($id). '" width="180">' .($task). ' </td>
```

I might be able to copy and rename all scripts, but I'm positive that's not the ideal way to do it. I tried to copy the script in the handler.php file and renamed the db fields, and did the same for the ajax script. But it didn't work. I hope my 'problem' is clear to you, any suggestions?

Note: I think the solution lies somewhere in this line (bottom of the ajax script):

```
.html("<form class=\"editor\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" class=\"editBox\" value=\"" + buffer + "\" /> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"buffer\" class=\"buffer\" value=\"" + buffer + "\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" class=\"record\" value=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\" /></form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Cancel</a>")
```

Thanks in advance for helping out! :)

Comment: Do you have to do this with jQuery, or can you just do this with basic javascript?  If your tool is making it difficult, this is a simple problem to do just with javascript, if that is an option.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply :) I really prefer to use this jQuery script because it works really well. I know there has to be a way to make more fields editable with the same script..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using the `Jeditable` jQuery plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and for a good example of various uses you can look at the demo page:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Also, I hope you are not actually going to use that php script to update the database, as that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, so it is bad practice.

And I don't see any element with the class `editable` in the html, just `editBox`.

And finally, you are submitting all the elements each time there is to be a change?  That is quite inefficient, as one advantage of editing in-place is to just send small changes each time.

Comment: Hello James, thank you for your extensive answer. I will try the Jeditable again, tried implanting it before but because I'm a beginner it's still a bit confusing to me. For the security part, can you point me to a great tutorial? It has something to do with _POST right? Thanks again for you're time and good day to you :)

Comment: @MaartenHartman - It has nothing to do with _POST, but with the fact that you are using the data directly in your database query. Here is an article about the problem: http://www.adamsinfo.com/security-consultant-php-developer-sql-injection-attacks/ and here is one tutorial: http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12442-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements.html